# Working with lengths in node shape definition

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-shape

This question is a bit tricky. I am trying to build symbols of flow charts for pneumatic circuits. I don't need that many elements, but I would like to be able to extend my collection similar to what `pgfcirkuitz` does (albeit not that sophisticated).
Therefore I wrote several definitions that draw common symbols, and I built a macro combining them to one specific node shape. I store one particular length in a `tikzset`. The whole flow works in the sense that it draws the symbol, but I get error messages of the kind `illegal unit of measure`. Can someone point me towards the error I made?

Below is my code, which unfortunately due to the attempt to make this thing customizable, is rather long for this particular question.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\makeatletter

\def\storecenter#1{%
    \pgf@process{#1}%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgf@x%
    \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgf@y%
}%

% empty flowpath square {centerpoint}{half sidelength}
\def\addemptyflowpath#1#2{%
    \storecenter{#1}
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners%
    {\pgf@x=\pgfutil@tempdima%
        \pgf@y=\pgfutil@tempdimb%
        \advance\pgf@x by-#2%
        \advance\pgf@y by-#2}%
    {\pgf@x=\pgfutil@tempdima%
        \pgf@y=\pgfutil@tempdimb%
        \advance\pgf@x by #2%
        \advance\pgf@y by #2}%
    \pgfusepath{draw}
}

\def\addflowpathbothways#1#2{%
    \storecenter{#1}
    % rectangle
    \addemptyflowpath{#1}{#2}
    % symbol
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdimb-#2}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdimb+#2}}
%    \pgfsetarrows{<->}
%    \pgfusepath{draw}
%    \pgfsetarrows{-}
}%

\long\def\declarecombindedflow#1#2#3#4{%
    \pgfdeclareshape{#1}{%
        \savedanchor{\centerpoint}{\pgfpointorigin}
        \saveddimen\numberofelements{\pgf@x=#2}
        \saveddimen\halfside{%
            \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pneumatic/flow path size}}%
        }
        \saveddimen\halfwidth{%
            \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{#2*0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pneumatic/flow path size}}%
        }
        \anchor{center}{\centerpoint}

        #3

        \backgroundpath{
            #4
        }%
    }%
}%

\makeatother

\tikzset{
    pneumatic/flow path size/.initial=20 cm,
}

\declarecombindedflow{combindedtest}{2}{}{%
    \newlength\shiftelement
    \pgfmathsetlength\shiftelement{(-(2+1)+1*2)*\halfside}
    \addflowpathbothways{\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{-\shiftelement}{0pt}}}{\halfside}
    \pgfmathsetlength\shiftelement{(-(2+1)+2*2)*\halfside}
    \addflowpathbothways{\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{-\shiftelement}{0pt}}}{\halfside}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[combindedtest, name=a] at (2,2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code you posted does not produce the `illegal unit` error, could you fix it so that it does?

Comment: On my machine, it does... That's weird.

Comment: It might eventually, but the first error is `Runaway definition?
#1#2#3#4->\pgfdeclareshape {#1}{\savedanchor {\centerpoint }{\pgfpointorigin \E
TC.
! File ended while scanning definition of \declarecombindedflow.
<inserted text> 
                }` due to a missing brace.

Comment: I'm sorry, copy/paste error. I fixed it. It also creates a `PGF Math Error`, but this should be due to the missing `center`-anchor, that is present in the original code. So I will add that line, too...

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of `\declarecombindedflow` uses `#2` as

```
\pgf@x=#2
```

This means, `#2` needs to be a length. So when you use your macro, you need to use:

```
\declarecombindedflow{combindedtest}{2pt}{}{% i.e. `2pt` instead of `2`.
```

Though, since `\numberofelements` doesn't sound like a length, it might be better to use [`\savedmacro`](https://tikz.dev/base-nodes#%5Csavedmacro), i.e.

```
\savedmacro\numberofelements{\pgfmathtruncatemacro\numberofelements{#2}}
```

and then you can use

```
\declarecombindedflow{combindedtest}{2}{}{%
```

again (or even `\declarecombindedflow{foo}{5*3-13}…`) and `\numberofelements` will be available and will expand to `2`.
(If you don't need PGFmath you can simply do `\savedmacro\numberofelements{\edef\numberofelement{#2}}`.)